# How to force Devel Generate to use default image when creating nodes?

Tags: debugging

I'm using Devel Generate to generate nodes which has an image field. The generation is working fine but devel uses a standar image (sort of color squares) for the created nodes instead of the default image I set in the content type of the node.

Is there any way to force Devel Generate to use the default image instead?